# Shortcut to run mintty.exe with ConEmu

Tags: cygwin, shortcuts, conemu, mintty

I'm trying to create a shortcut to start Cygwin's mintty.exe (logged in with default config) in ConEmu.
The only way I was able to start mintty inside ConEmu via shortcut was by defining the shortcut's target to:

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" "C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe"
```

This will start mintty inside ConEmu, but it will lack Cygwin functionalities.

To start mintty.exe with default Cygwin config one needs to pass a command (a single minus) to mintty.exe link this:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -
```

I was trying the following without success (see the minus):

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" "C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Only one idea actually - I'm wasting time writing documentation. That's really sad. http://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html

Comment: Next time I'll check there.
Time not wasted!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Maximus points out: The answer can be found here: [ConEmu Documentation > ConEmu.exe command line switches](http://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html)

This shortcut target:

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" /cmd {MinntyTaskName}
```

will start Minnty hooked up with Cygwin if you create a proper Task for Minnty inside ConEmu *(Settings > Startup > Tasks)*, with this Command:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want a Windows shortcut so instead I added the Task as you pointed out, then I checked the "Default shell" checkbox. Works great.